# AC currents for self-inductance of a wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, approximations, inductance

I've been currently reading some stuff on self-inductance of a wire. There are different regimes where different approximations are used. For the AC currents the notes state that an approximation can be made when

> "For a straight cylindrical tube of infinitesimal thickness, or for alternating current of great frequency when there is no magnetic field within the wire"

Anyone could help me in understanding how a alternating current of great frequency could have no magnetic field within the wire?

Comment: You may need to provide more context. I don't see how a large AC current would prevent a B-field within the wire, if the B-field is generated by the current.

Comment: i changed it around, better?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to what's called [the skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect). Basically, if you initially had a uniform current density within the wire, if this current starts varying rapidly, the current flowing close to the cylinder axis induces magnetic fields around the axis. These in turn induce currents that flow in the opposite direction near the axis, according to Lenz's law, and eventually cancels the current flowing near the axis. At sinusoidal steady state, the only allowed solution is where current only flows in a region close to the surface of the conductor, with thickness given (in good conductors) by
$$ \delta = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sigma\omega\mu}} $$
which is called the skin depth. Here $\sigma$ is the electrical conductivity, $\mu$ is the permeability and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. It can be shown by applying Ampere's law and the cylindrical symmetry of the wire geometry that the magnetic field is also zero within the wire, except for the region where current flows.

Comment: is $\delta$ a phenomenological parameter or is there a way to compute $\omega$ be equating $\delta$ to something else?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. $\omega$ is the frequency of the current. $\delta$ is the characteristic thickness within which the current and magnetic field are confined. This formula is an approximation valid for high conductivity. See the link for details.

Comment: Magnetic field can't induce current in stationary conductor. The skin effect is due to induced electric field of the current-forming charges counteracting the Coulomb electric field that drives the whole process.

Comment: I think this is a matter of semantics. Yes, the emfs, and thus currents, are due to an E-field, but the E-field canceling the current within the conductor is induced by a time-varying magnetic field.

Comment: @JanLalinsky This is not a comment but an answer. Moreover, as the wire typically is electrically neutral, where should a Coulomb field come from? Another point is that a time varying field is _exactly the same thing_ as the rotation of an electric field. E and B do not induce each other but instead are mutually dependent quantities.

Comment: @my2cts I agree with your point about E and B being mutually dependent quantities. Maxwell's equations say nothing about the causal relationship between E and B, but sometimes it is just convenient to imagine such a relationship, especially when explaining phenomena ("time-varying B-field 'inducing' an E-field" etc.).

Comment: @Puk A time varying magnetic field induces a _current_. You can interpret that current driven by an electric field.

Comment: @my2cts Again, I think for the most part it is harmless to think of the E-field as having been "induced" by a time-varying B-field. Ultimately, Maxwell's equations are all that matter, how we describe the relation of E and B in words is unimportant. It _is_ the E-field driving the current in this case, according to the Lorentz force law.

Comment: @Puk We understand the world and teach by using words. We cannot afford to discard language in favour of Maxwell solvers. To "induce" implies a cause and effect relation that simply is not there.

Comment: @my2cnts Very well, we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @Puk you are right, but your wording in your answer suggests (to beginners) that magnetic field itself induces some electric currents. This has potential to confuse, it is better to write changing magnetic field means there is also induced electric field, and that electric field then influences current.

Comment: @my2cts the Coulomb field is due to all electric charges on the surface of the conductors nearby - wires, terminals, other elements in the circuit. These are not exactly electrically neutral; if they were, there couldn't be electric field inside them.

Comment: @JanLalinsky An AC electric field can also be due to a changing current, do a changing magnetic field. It does not require net charge so it does not have to be a Coulomb field.

Comment: @my2cts in general yes the driving force for current may be due to induced electric field of another current instead of Coulomb field, but in practice HV power transmission lines don't work that way, there is no other current nearby that could induce the necessary field. Instead there is gradient of electric potential along the wire and thus distribution of charges on its surface that produces that gradient.

Comment: @my2cts there is no induced field in DC situation yet there is electric field inside the wires. This is the Coulomb field. In AC this mechanism is present as well, only induced field is an additional field that makes things more interesting.

Comment: @JanLalinsky In the AC case there is no Coulomb field.